# Checking if valid date in C# not working properly

Tags: c#, validation, date

I am using the following function to determine whether input string is valid date or not.

```
public static bool IsDate(string date)
        {
            DateTime Temp;

            if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out Temp))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
```

Problem is when I give input "1997-09" then it returns true. I want it to check complete date like "1997-08-12"

And no there is no fix date format. Input could also be "19-Feb-2012"

Comment: There must be a list of correct date formats. How else would you know the date is not correct?

Comment: 1997-08-12 how one can tell is it december or august by looking at it with a format being told?

Comment: @Adil - by the localization settings on the computer where the program is running.

Comment: @Adil
In this case it will always yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: I think parsing acccoding to culture info might help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya.aspx

Comment: What is in Temp after parsing "1997-09"? Which culture are tou using? It's really strange!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one easy condition you can add:

```
    public static bool IsDate(string date)
    {
        DateTime Temp;
        return(DateTime.TryParse(date, out Temp)&&date.Length>=10)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

> And no there is no fix date format. Input could also be "19-Feb-2012"

There must be, otherwise it's nonesense. If you haven't defined how your system must behave you'd better stop coding and take a moment to define it.

You could use the [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) method which allows you to specify one or more formats you would like to handle.

Answer (score 2):

You should establish list of a correct date formats and then check with `DateTime.TryParseExact`, something like this:

```
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
DateTime dateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime.TryParse, you can specify the format then, more here.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can return result of parsing directly:

```
public static bool IsDate(string value)
{
    DateTime date;
    return DateTime.TryParse(value, out date);
}
```

And it works with formats you have provided (at least when current culture "en-US").

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this you should define a `datetime-format` in your applicaiton.

On any webpage you go, if you see a compilation form, you probabbly will will see some date field too, and near it something like:

`DD-MM-YYYY`, or `MM/DD/YY`, or somethign else .

Define for your application format, make it esplicit for the user and check on correctness according to *your* format.

Just an hypothetic example:

say user inserted a date and you store it into the string like `DD-MM-YYYY`, one of possible choice could be simply say :

```
if(dateTimeUserString.Split('-').Length < 3)
    //not valid string !
```

I repeat, this is just an example you should choose more appropriate way for your application.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.TryParse does have an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that takes an IFormatProvider to allow specification of custom formats.  You may need to define multiple IFormatPrividers to check the various strings you may expect as valid.

Also, rather than the if/else, you could also shorten your code a bit by

```
return DateTime.TryParse(date, out Temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will run just fine and check the given date string if it can be a valid date using all of the **current culture's** date formats including this `19-Feb-2012` or `1997-09` of yours or even `19 february`.

This makes you flexible in date input.

But if flexibility is not what your are looking for then try to parse for one or more specific formats using `TryParseExact`.